# "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" when Inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, primary-key

I'm getting the above error when running an insert into on one of our tables.

The AdmFormData has 3 primary keys, FormType, KeyField and FieldName.

Would anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
    set rowcount 0
    go



    INSERT INTO  AdmFormData
    (
    [FormType]
      ,[KeyField]
      ,[FieldName]
      ,[AlphaValue]
      ,[NumericValue]
      ,[DateValue]
    )
    SELECT
     'CUS' AS [FormType]
      ,Customer as [KeyField]
      ,'SAL001' AS [FieldName]
      ,[Customer Territory] AS [AlphaValue]
      ,NULL AS [NumericValue]
      ,NULL AS [DateValue]
    FROM
    dgl_territory a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN AdmFormData f
    on f.FormType = 'CUS' and f.FieldName = 'SAL001' and f.KeyField = a.Customer
    WHERE f.FormType IS NULL
```

Comment: I take it this is for SQL Server? The tags were set to both MySQL and SQLite, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you already have a record in the `AdmFormData` table that has the primary key you are trying to `INSERT`

If your primary key on the table contains `FormType, KeyField and FieldName` then you already have a record with the values:

```
'CUS' AS [FormType]
,Customer as [KeyField]
,'SAL001' AS [FieldName]
```

You cannot have more that one record with the same primary key, they are unique.

Comment: but if I run on our test db with no records it still displays the same error?

Comment: @LewisCooksey what results do you get when you just run the `SELECT` portion of the query?

Comment: if you run a `SELECT` query against the `AdmFormData` do you have data in the table?

Comment: Yes, there is data, and I see what you mean about PK, but other instances in this table have duplicates.

Comment: It cannot have duplicates on all three fields if that is what makes up the primary key. You can have multiple fields that match but not all three on several records, that would violate the PK.

Comment: I understand that, which is what baffles me.  For instance if I `SELECT` `WHERE FormType ='CUS' AND FieldName = 'SAL001'` it returns no results

Comment: without seeing sample data from your table it would be guesswork on my part.

Comment: Nailed it. `on f.FormType = 'CUS' and f.FieldName = 'SAL001' and f.KeyField = a.Customer`  should have simplified this `f.KeyField = a.Customer`  Thanks for all your help.